# Dart: override method which is also parameter in constructor

Tags: dart, dynamic, constructor, overriding

I'd like to do the following:

```
abstract class MyInterface {
  late dynamic Function() someThing;
  // other stuff
}

class A implements MyInterface {
  A({required this.someThing});
  @override
  String Function() someThing;
  // overrides of other stuff
}

class B implements MyInterface {
  B({required this.someThing});
  @override
  int Function() someThing;
  // overrides of other stuff
}
```

All classes that implement MyInterface should have a function that returns whatever as parameter in their constructor.

I get "Missing concrete implementations"-error, so I just leave "something" out of MyInterface as a solution. But it would be nice to have it inside.

Comment: Is this your actual code and actual error?  Your "Missing concrete implementations" error occurs because (in the original version of this question) the `A` and `B` child classes implement fields named `someThing` but the base class interface expects an implementation for `something` (note the different capitalization).  After you fix that, you will get a *different* error about `A` and `B` having setters that aren't valid overrides.  One way to fix that would be make `MyInterface` require only a getter: `dynamic Function() get someThing;`